# Vimperator :: exit insert mode in a textarea

Tags: vimperator

For some websites, which grab the focus to a textarea, it's not even possible to exit the "insert" mode in any other way except doing a mouse-click outside the textarea.

Is there any common workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Ctrl-[ to exit insert mode.

Comment: On Hungarian keyboard the [ character can be reached as AltGr+f. And Ctrl+AltGr+f not works to escape from insert mode. :-(

Comment: But now I haven't entered command mode in the text area, I have simply stopped editing the text area. Is this expected? I'm trying to use Firefox and Vimperator simply for a permanent vim-mode in text areas. How to enable? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For those who cannot reach `[` directly on the keyboard, I managed to map `Ctrl-[` to `Ctrl-#`:

```
:imap <C-#> <C-[>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use "b" in order to get the command line with buffers. 
then i replace "buffers" with "q".